# Pivot select tables in dataframe to make values column headers in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to transform and pivot select values.
I wish to groupby id and date, sum the 'pwr' values and then count the type values.

**df**

**df values that will be column headers:  'hi', 'hey'**

```
id  date    type    pwr de_id   de_date de_type de_pwr  base    base_pos
aa  q1      hey     10  aa      q1      hey     5       200     40
aa  q1      hi      5                                   200     40
aa  q1      hey     5                                   200     40
aa  q2      hey     2   aa      q2      hey     3       200     40
aa  q2      hey     2   aa      q2      hey     3       200     40
bb  q1              0   bb      q1      hi      6       500     10
bb  q1              0   bb      q1      hi      6       500     10
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    hey hi  total   sum  hey hi  totald desum   base base_pos
aa  q1      2   1   3       20   1   0   1      5       200  40       
aa  q2      2   0   2       4    2   0   2      6       200  40       
bb  q1      0   0   0       0    0   2   2      12      500  10
```

**Doing**

```
sum1 = df.groupby(['id','date']).agg({'pwr': 'sum', 'type': 'count', 'de_pwr': 'sum', 'de_type': 'count'})
pd.pivot_table(df, values = '' , columns = 'type')
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is definitely not a 'clean' way to go around it, but since you have 2 separate totals summing along columns, I don't know how much cleaner it could get (and the output seems accurate).

You don't mention what aggregation you use to get `base` and `base_pos` values, so I went with `mean` (might need to change it).

```
type_col = pd.crosstab(index = [df['id'], df['date']], columns = df['type'])
type_col['total'] = type_col.sum(axis = 1)
pwr_sum = df.groupby(['id','date'])['pwr'].sum()
de_type_col = pd.crosstab(index = [df['id'], df['date']], columns = df['de_type'])
de_type_col['total_de'] = de_type_col.sum(axis = 1)
pwr_de_sum = df.groupby(['id','date'])['de_pwr'].sum()
base_and_pos = df.groupby(['id','date'])[['base','base_pos']].mean()
out = pd.concat([type_col, pwr_sum, de_type_col, pwr_de_sum, base_and_pos], axis = 1).fillna(0).astype('int')
```

Essentially use `crosstab` to get value counts and sum them along columns. The index of resulting DataFrame is the same as `groupby(['id','date'])`, so you can then concatenate results of groupby without issue. Repeat the same process for `de` columns, apply groupby with your choice of aggregation to `base` and `base_pos` columns, and concatenate all results along `axis = 1`. Obviously, you can group some operations together (such as `pwr` sum, `de_pwr` sum and `base`/`base_pos` aggregation), but you'll need to reorder your columns after that to get the desired order.

Output:

```
id  date    hey hi  total   pwr hey hi  total_de    de_pwr  base    base_pos
aa  q1      2   1   3       20  1   0   1           5       200     40
aa  q2      2   0   2       4   2   0   2           6       200     40
bb  q1      0   0   0       0   0   2   2           12      500     10
```

Comment: ok sure , yes the base and base_pos are just constant values that are associated w the 'id'
I just wanted to include those in the dataset.
Ill try this, thank you